# Glide: Non ImageView target compression/resizing by default?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-image

I am loading a `Google Map` `GroundOverlay` with `Glide` like this

```
Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("url")
            .into(updateOverlayTarget2)
```

with target being

```
private val updateOverlayTarget = object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            val bounds = LatLngBounds(LatLng(34.5362, -96.9535), LatLng(39.9342, -89.8475))
            val overlay = GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource))
                .positionFromBounds(bounds)

            googleMap1?.addGroundOverlay(overlay)
        }
    }
```

This works great for me. But when I download the remote image put it in `drawable` folder and instead of using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource)` I use `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId)` I immediately get an OutOf Memory error. My image has alpha channel in it.

I am little confused here. `Glide` must not be using default `RGB_565` here as there is no alpha in this format. Is it doing some other compression?

Answer (score 0):

> Glide must not be using default RGB_565 here as there is no alpha in
>   this format. Is it doing some other compression?

If you will try to directly use a **new image** from drawable in `onResourceReady` it will most probably throw an OOM if the image is big because it hasn't been loaded yet.

You have to load the image from drawable asynchronously, for example:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(R.drawable.your_image)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                // Now here you can use resource
            }
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            }
        })
```

Or you can use this also to get the bitmap synchronously

```
val bitmap = Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(R.drawable.your_image)
            .submit().get()
```

Comment: I don't understand. What difference does it make if the image is loaded `synchronously` or `asynchronously`on memory footprint?

Comment: `.submit().get()` will return image synchronously

Comment: Sorry corrected the mistake. In terms of memory usage, both images will take the same amount of memory, `asynchronous` doesn't freeze the UI while loading.

Comment: okay, thanks for your effort but my question is about memory footprint of image when loading with Glide and without in a non view target

Comment: FYI `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId)` is from maps SDK. When using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource)` you are using a pre-loaded in memory (By Glide) image while by using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId)` you are trying to use a new image without Glide.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. Thats exactly is my question. How come I am getting OOM in one method for same image.